# Why all gods are blessed or born only in India? Why USA/UK is superior than India (Bharatha khandam) presently in 21st century?

Tags: vishnu, gods, yuga, kali-yuga, india

How was the America/USA/UK during previous yuga before Kali yuga?

Who were ruling those places? why god never born in USA/UK/Aus/NZ/china geographic region (non-India) during Satya, Thretra yuga,Dwapara Yuga.

Why all our hindu gods majorly born or stories says only bharatha khandam. what about other khandams during ancient era/yugas?

Why USA/UK is superior than India (Bharatha khandam) presently in 21st century? 
When India/Bharat becomes Number-1 country in entire world and universe?

**When 1000KWD(kuwait Dinar) = ₹1 and $1000 = ₹1 and £1000 = ₹1 and €1000 = ₹1 ? Which year in Kaliyuga?**

Why India[God's own country] has lost Sri/Lakshmi and becomes poverty and poor?

Why Lakshmi devi not blessing bharat desh to get rid from poverty and poor and not blessing to become number-1 country in the world/universe in wealth, knowledge, wisdom,vijay parampara defeating all countries in the world and When bharat desh regains as Number-1 country ?

Comment: USA/UK/Canada etc are predominantly materialistic worlds, spirituality is opposite of this world!

Comment: bharata is karma bhumi, punya bhumi.. in other 3 yugas, people living outside bharata were mlecchas (those who did not follow vedas and were outside the 4 varnas). but in Kali Yuga, Bhagavan being the ocean of mercy, realized if he confined himself to Bharata, the degraded humans would fall deeper into samsara.. hence he sent Jesus & Mohammed to improve those folks outside Bharat. Probably in future, he might send someone to America, who knows his Lila ?

Comment: As to why other nations are superior (in wealth, not spirituality though), it's because Lakshmi Kataksham on those places. The gaze will turn eastwards soon.

Comment: Why Lakshmi Kataksham not shower or blesses now in Bharat desh to become No.1 desh in 21st century in all parameters including devotion and super rich in wealth, wisdom, knowledge etc? Why Lakshmi Kataksham showering in those nations(non-India)? Why God not interfering anything now and just becomes silent or witness of one's self activities without exhibiting his/her powers now?

Comment: why does Indra not always control Svarga Loka ? how come Asura beat Indra and take over sometime ? Why Pandavas not always control Indraprastha ? Why Kamsa was able to torment brahmanas ? Why Rakshasas were able to hurt rishis ? It's all part of samsara. Aishwarya is not eternal. Comes and goes..

Comment: Why are young people impatient with the Karma Bhoomi and escape to US/UK? Why is India so slow  emulating them?

Comment: If you want material rewards, they are masters of the material universe. When it comes to spirituality, they are babies. India remains the master of the spiritual realm.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, yes. Bharat always was, is, and will be the guiding spiritual light.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based and off-topic since it deals with politics.